# Error while installing android platform in cordova

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am getting an error while installing Android platform in `Cordova` using Ionic.
Below is the image of error .

[image]

Please help me with this .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: did you try to remove cordova-plugin-console and add it again?